# How to measure the execution time of a query on Spark

Tags: sql, time, apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I need to measure the execution time of query on Apache spark (Bluemix).
What I tried:

```
import time

startTimeQuery = time.clock()
df = sqlContext.sql(query)
df.show()
endTimeQuery = time.clock()
runTimeQuery = endTimeQuery - startTimeQuery
```

Is it a good way? The time that I get looks too small relative to when I see the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**
No, using `time` package is not the best way to measure execution time of Spark jobs. The most convenient and exact way I know of is to use the Spark History Server.

On Bluemix, in your notebooks go to the "Paelette" on the right side. Choose the "Evironment" Panel and you will see a link to the Spark History Server, where you can investigate the performed Spark jobs including computation times.

Comment: I know the OP accepted the answer, but strangely enough it doesn't literally answer his question i.e., using time.clock() to measure the query execution time. I had the same question, that's why I ended up here, but at the end there is no answer.

Comment: @nadjib-mami
Ops, good point, missed the simple "No" and went directly to the solution :)
Thanks!

Comment: It still didn't answer, why using `time` is not the best way to measure

Answer (score 24):

To do it in a spark-shell (Scala), you can use `spark.time()`.

See another response by me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289329/3397114

```
df = sqlContext.sql(query)
spark.time(df.show())
```

The output would be:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|val1|val2|
+----+----+
Time taken: xxx ms
```

Related: [On Measuring Apache Spark Workload Metrics for Performance Troubleshooting](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-03-measuring-apache-spark-workload-metrics-performance-troubleshooting).

Comment: is there something that i should including as part of my jupyter to execute spark.time.. it is showing that AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'time' ( I am using pyspark.. is this only available in the scala version?)

Comment: @EB I was using Scala on EMR. I don't know whether PySpark has `time()`

Comment: @Tyrone321 It doesn't. (Still)

Comment: It doesn't. (Still)

Answer (score 14):

I use `System.nanoTime` wrapped around a  helper function, like this -

```
def time[A](f: => A) = {
  val s = System.nanoTime
  val ret = f
  println("time: "+(System.nanoTime-s)/1e6+"ms")
  ret
}

time {
  df = sqlContext.sql(query)
  df.show()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

SPARK itself provides much granular information about each stage of your Spark Job.

You can view your running job on http://IP-MasterNode:4040 or You can enable History server for analyzing the jobs at a later time.

Refer [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) for more info on History server.

Comment: The OP is asking about the Apache Spark Service on Bluemix, so not running their own spark cluster under their own control; e.g. it does not expose the ui on 4040.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using spark-shell (scala) you can use the `time` module:

```
import time
df = sqlContext.sql(query)
spark.time(df.show())
```

However, `SparkSession.time()` is not available in `pyspark`. For `python`, a simple solution would be to use `time`:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
df.show()
print(f"Execution time: {time.time() - start_time}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using [sparkMeasure](https://github.com/LucaCanali/sparkMeasure) which simplify the collection of performance metrics

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31454863)

Answer (score -2):

For those looking for / needing a python version
(as pyspark google search leads to this post) :

```
from time import time
from datetime import timedelta

class T():
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.end = time()
        elapsed = self.end - self.start
        print(str(timedelta(seconds=elapsed)))
```

Usage :

```
with T():
    //spark code goes here
```

As inspired by :
https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-create-your-own-timing-context-manager-in-python-a0e944b48cf8

Proved useful when using console or whith notebooks
(jupyter magic %%time an %timeit are limited to cell scope, which is inconvenient when you have shared objects across notebook context)