# spark query execution time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a local hadoop single node and hive installed and I have some hive tables stored in hdfs. Then I configure Hive with MySQL Metastore. And now I installed spark and Im doing some queries over hive tables like this (in scala):

```
var hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
result = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM USERS");
result.show
```

Do you know how to configure spark to show to the execution time of the query? Because for default it is not showing..

Comment: Possible duplicate of this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629313/how-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-a-query-on-spark

Comment: OMG, isn't there anyone who finally doesn't suggest to visit a web browser to get the execution time?! can't believe it. This has to also be possible **programmatically**.

Answer (score 2):

Use `spark.time()`.

`var hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
result = hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM USERS");
spark.time(result.show)`

https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-03-measuring-apache-spark-workload-metrics-performance-troubleshooting