# why the Job running time and command execution time not matching in databricks notebook?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-notebook

I have a azure databricks job and it's triggered via ADF using a api call. I want see why the job has been taking n minutes to complete the tasks. When the job execution results, The job execution time says 15 mins and the individual cells/commands doesn't add up to even 4-5 mins

The interactive cluster is already up and running while this got triggered. Please tell me why this sum of individual cell execution time doesn't match with the overall job execution time ? Where can i see what has taken the additional time here ?

Comment: Did you check the output log in ADF to find out is there any latency issues from ADF to DBX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below reference it has detail explanation about:

- Execution time taken for the command cell in data bricks notebook.
- Measuring Apache Spark Workload Metrics for Performance.

**Reference:**

[How to measure the execution time of a query on Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629313/how-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-a-query-on-spark)

https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-03-measuring-apache-spark-workload-metrics-performance-troubleshooting

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html