How to evaluate total execution connection time in BigTable from Spark by scala
I am attempting to measure the total execution time from Spark to BigTable. However, when I wrap the following code around the BigTable related function, it consistently shows only 0.5 seconds, regardless of the data volume I extract:
val t0 = System.nanoTime()
// Get the dataframe after querying data from Bigtable function
val df = queryDataBigtable()
val t1 = System.nanoTime()
val elapsedTime = (t1 - t0) / 1e9d // Convert nanoseconds to seconds
println(s"Elapsed time: $elapsedTime seconds")

To ensure that Spark performs actual work, I tried using df.count. However, since this is production code, I’m hesitant to rely on .count for monitoring the query time for Bigtable from Spark. Do you have any better suggestions for monitoring bigtable time?

What does queryDataBigtable do? I suspect it's doing nothing apart defining a Dataframe. But a Dataframe is not evaluated until you call an action like count/cache/... Thus it would be expected that you observe almost 0 time spent.

Partially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629313/how-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-a-query-on-spark

Yeah... Aftrer I test, they don't get executed until an action (like count, collect, show, etc.) is called. Thanks @GaëlJ.
